# Why is the relation "$f=g $ almost everywhere" transitive?

Tags: measure-theory

In Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, it says on pg 27 that

If $\mu$ be a measure, define $f\sim g$ iff $\mu(\{x|f(x)≠g(x)\})=0$, where $f,g$ are measurable functions from $X$ to a topological space $Y$.

Then, $f\sim g$ is an equivalence relation.

But, I do not see why $f\sim g$ is transitive.

If I assume $f\sim g$ and $g\sim h$, then by definition, $\{x|f(x)≠g(x)\}$ and $\{x|g(x)≠h(x)\}$ are measurable sets with measure zero.

But then, how do I know that the set $\{x|f(x)≠h(x)\} \subset \{x|f(x)≠g(x)\} \cup  \{x|g(x)≠h(x)\} $ is measurable?

Here $Y$ is a topological space, not necessarily $R$ or extended reals.

Comment: @JasonKnapp I do not see why that is true

Comment: $Y$ is a totally general top. space?  No assumptions whatsoever?

Comment: @MJD if I understand the question this is about measurability rather than computing the measure.  The question does not assume that the measure space is complete.

Comment: @MJD That I know, but what I do not know is that the subsets of $A \cup B$ is measurable to begin with

Comment: @JasonKnapp I do not see any assumption on $Y$

Comment: One step further, is converge in measure transitive? Converge a.e is transitive, same as the equivalence relation.

Answer (score 3):

Rudin's has this definition: property $P$ holds a.e. on $E$ iff there is a null set $N \subset E$ such that $P$ holds at every point of $E - N$.  It does not say $\{x\;|\; P\text{ holds at }x\}$ is measurable.  With this notion, the transitivity is OK.

But then he goes and ruins it by saying $f=g$ a.e. means $\mu(\{x\;|\;f(x) \ne g(x)\})=0$, implicitly requiring $\{x\;|\;f(x)\ne g(x)\}$ to be measurable.  As you note, in case $Y$ is a weird topological space where the diagonal is not closed in $Y \times Y$, we cannot conclude that $\{x\;|\;f(x)\ne g(x)\}$ is measurable for measurable functions $f,g$.

Of course Rudin applies the notion "$f=g$ a.e." only in cases when $Y$ is metrizable, where there is no problem.

Comment: Rudin does require $E$ to be measurble AND $N$ to be measurable, which forces $\{x| P holds at x\}$ to be measurable

Comment: Rudin merely says $P$ holds at every point of $E - N$.  So what if $E-N$ is a measruable set?  It is allowed that $P$ also holds at some points in $N$.  Perhaps even on a non-measurable subset of $N$.

Comment: I have the 1966 Edition as well, but it says on pg 27  that "if $\mu$ is a meausre a sigam albera M and if $E\in M $, the statement P holds a.e. on E means that there exists an $N\in M$ such that $\mu(N) = 0$, $N\subset E$ and $P$ holds at every point on $E-N$.

Comment: So, he does say $E$ is mesurable and $N$ is measurable

Comment: It just came to my attention that Rudin does say on the next page(p28) that "since every measure can be completed, we may assume that any given measure is complete", which solves our problem

Comment: @GEdgar assuming $Y$ would be a Hausdorff space where the diagonal is closed in $Y\times Y$, why would then $\{x \mid f(x) \not= g(x)\}$ be measurable?

Answer (score 2):

So here is our example.  As noted in the other answers, we need $\mathfrak M$ not complete, and $Y$ not metrizable.

Let $X = \mathbb R$, $\mathfrak M =$ Borel sets, $\mu =$ Lebesgue measure.
Let $Y = \mathbb R$, indiscrete topology.  The only open sets are $\varnothing, \mathbb R$.

Because $Y$ is indiscrete, every function $f \;:\; X \to Y$ is measurable.

Let $N \subseteq X$ be the Cantor set, a Borel null set;
and let $K \subseteq N$ be non-measurable.  There are $2^{\mathfrak c}$ subsets of $N$, but only $\mathfrak c$ Borel sets, so certainly there is
such a set $K$.  Now define
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}0,\qquad x \in K
\\0,\qquad x \in N - K
\\0,\qquad x \in \mathbb R - N\end{cases}
\\
g(x) = \begin{cases}1,\qquad x \in K
\\1,\qquad x \in N - K
\\0,\qquad x \in \mathbb R - N\end{cases}
\\
h(x) = \begin{cases}0,\qquad x \in K
\\2,\qquad x \in N - K
\\0,\qquad x \in \mathbb R - N\end{cases}
$$
Then:
$f=g$ a.e. since $\{x \mid f(x) \ne g(x)\} = N$ is a measurable null set.
$g=h$ a.e. since $\{x \mid g(x) \ne h(x)\} = N$ is a measurable null set.
But **not** $f=h$ a.e., since $\{x \mid f(x) \ne h(x)\} = K$ is not measurable.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

The following argument works only if the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is complete.:

If $x$ satisfies $f(x) \neq h(x)$, then it satisfies exactly one of the following three cases:

a) $f(x) \neq g(x)$ and $g(x) = h(x)$

b) $f(x) = g(x)$ and $g(x) \neq h(x)$

c) $f(x) \neq g(x)$ and $g(x) \neq h(x)$

Then if we let $$A = \{x \mid f(x) \neq g(x) \} \cap \{x \mid g(x) = h(x) \}$$ $$B = \{x \mid f(x) = g(x) \} \cap \{x \mid g(x) \neq h(x) \}$$ $$C = \{x \mid f(x) \neq g(x) \} \cap \{x \mid g(x) \neq h(x) \}$$ we have $\{x \mid f(x) \neq h(x) \} \subseteq A \cup B \cup C$.  Since $A, B,$ and $C$ are sets of measure $0$, their union is also a set of measure $0$, and thus so is $\{x \mid f(x) \neq h(x)\}$ (since the $\sigma$-algebra is complete).

Comment: First of all, since $Y$ is a topological space, $f-h$ is not always well defined though

Comment: @hle I updated my answer.

Comment: Some points where $f(x)=h(x)$ may be in set $C$.

Comment: @Gedgar Ok, what if we say $\{x \mid f(x) \neq h(x) \} \subseteq A \cup B \cup C$?  And $A \cup B \cup C$ has measure $0$ since $A$, $B$, and $C$ do.

Comment: Great.  But hle complains we cannot conclude that $\{x \mid f(x) \neq h(x) \}$ is measurable.

Comment: I guess the problem is that we don't know that $\{x \mid f(x) \neq h(x) \}$ is measurable, which is the whole point.  If the $\sigma$-algebra were complete, we would know this.

Comment: @GEdgar exactly :)

Comment: @hle What is the $\sigma$-algebra associated with $X$?

Comment: @user46944 Rudin does not specify, but I assume it is just any sigma algebra

Comment: @hle For now, let's conclude it's true if the $\sigma$-algebra is complete. lol

Comment: @user46944 It just came to my attention that Rudin does say on the next page(p28) that "since every measure can be completed, we may assume that any given measure is complete", which solves our problem!